# Forming a trie object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, trie

So, I am trying to make a trie that associates words in a sentence, rather than prefixes of words. I have managed to do so already in Python, as follows:

```
#statement trie

class strie (object):

def __init__(self):
    self.trie = {}
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.trie)
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.trie)
def statement(self, phrase):
    words = phrase.split()
    current = self.trie
    while len(words) > 0:
        word = words.pop(0)
        if word in current.keys():
            current = current[word]
        else:
            current[word] = {}
            current = current[word]
```

And i would get the result by testing:

```
       r
=> {'The': {'apple': {'is': {'red': {}, 'blue': {'or': {'yellow': {}}}}}}}
```

However, when i implement this nearly identically with javascript, something strange happens. Here is my implementation for it in javascript:

```
    //constructs a trie formed form a single sentence as an object.
function single_trie(phrase) {
    phrase = phrase.toLowerCase();
    var trie = {};
    var words = phrase.split(" ");
    var current = trie;
    while (words.length > 0) {
        var word = words.shift();
        if(word in current) current = current[word];
        else {
            current[word] = {};
            current = current[word];
        }
    }
    return trie;
}
```

And I get this really strange result:

```
    var strie = single_trie("the apple is red and blue");
console.log(strie);

{ the: { apple: { is: [Object] } } }
```

What is causing this to happen with my javascript implementation? Why does it show [Object]? How can I get it to work like my python implementation?

Comment: There is no error - it is just how `console.log` displays on your browser; you can expand the object to show more depth. The data is all there. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(strie))` for a non-interactive display.

Comment: If you're using Node.js, you may also try [`console.dir()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/console.html#console_console_dir_obj_options), which lets you increase the max depth – `console.dir(strie, { depth: 10 })`. (Note: default is `2`.)

Comment: Oh that worked! I get it now.